# How to remove new line, carriage and horizontal tab from the beginning and ending of a string?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am taking data from the users which can be very unreliable. So before saving it in the PostgreSQL DB, I have to clear all the extra character in the beginning and the ending of the string.

1. Is this Possible to achieve?

   ```
   '   \n \t \n \r\n abc_def_\n xyz \r\n  ' to 'abc_def_\n xyz'
   ```
2. Are there any more whitespace like characters that I should care about?

   ```
   \n  newline
   \r  carriage return
   \t  horizontal tab
   whitespace
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have thought that `\s` would cover all whitespace, but that doesn't seem to be the case with Postgres' `REGEXP_REPLACE`.  Instead, I got good mileage using the character class `[\r\n\t ]` to represent all the whitespace you want to remove.  Also, you really want to *trim* such whitespace only from the beginning and end of the column, and not in middle, so we can search on the following regex pattern:

```
^[\r\n\t ]*|[\r\n\t ]*$
```

and then replace with just empty string, to remove it.

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '   \n \t \n \r\n abc_def_\n xyz \r\n  '::text AS col
)

SELECT
    col,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '^[\\r\\n\\t ]*|[\\r\\n\\t ]*$', '', 'g') AS col_updated
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: doesn't actually work ( `+` should be `*` ) suppose `'this '`  as input.

Answer (score 2):

There's already a function for that. no need to use regex.

```
select trim( e'\t\n\r\ ' from ' your string ' );
```

Comment: trim can work individually but not working this way.

Comment: @Deepakgupta  
it works here.  `select trim('crab' from 'abracadabra');` result `d`